# Alguém conhece o framework Ionic?

Tags: html, ionic

Vcs conhecem o framework Ionic? É similar ao PhoneGap.

Comment: Qual a sua duvida ou problema exatamente?

Comment: Quero aprender a mexer nele.

Comment: Neste caso você deve procurar por matérias e cursos sobre o assunto e em caso de duvidas deve postar aqui. O site é sobre duvidas e problemas específicos. Maiores informações você encontra neste link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é que seja similar, ele usa o próprio PhoneGap.

O Ionic não substitui o mesmo, ele é voltado para aparência e funcionalidades mas a plataforma é o Cordova ( PhoneGap ). Atualmente ele usa o angular JS então é bom sabê-lo também.

Leia isso é muito útil:

http://ionicframework.com/blog/where-does-the-ionic-framework-fit-in/

E se quiser aprender mais sobre ele indico: https://thinkster.io/ionic-framework-tutorial/

Comment: vc já usou ou usa o Ionic?

Comment: @GustavoSevero sim, uso e já usei. Esse aplicativo na qual já trabalhei é criado com ele: http://www.makemynight.com.br/

Comment: Falando no Ionic, aqui um link de um artigo lançado recentemente em portugues: http://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-ionic-framework/